# Double-pole breaker but all 120 V receptacles

Tags: electrical, canada

I'm trying to map outlets to breakers in my house and noticed that there is a double-pole, 15A breaker that control outlets/ceiling lights in my garage but they are all 120V (15A) receptacles.

How is that possible? What confuses me is that I thought double-pole breakers are supposed to be 240V, not 120V.

EDIT: Added image below from the home inspection report

[image: Circuit breaker]

Comment: Photo of the breaker would be nice :) Are the wires in the circuit 14ga, suitable for no more than 15A? Are the receptacles themselves rated for 15A? Could you clarify what aspect of the setup is puzzling you?

Comment: The receptacles are 15A, not 20A (there is no terminal with the sideways T). What confuses me is that I thought double-pole breakers are 240V, not 120V.

Comment: Could be a multi wire branch circuit (MWBC) where there are two hot wires on different phases but only 1 shared neutral wire. The idea would be that each outlet would be powered by one or the other hot wire, not both, so 120V. There are special requirements to make this work safely; since I am not fully knowledgeable on those, I will let one of the forum experts post a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

Each single-pole breaker protects a single hot 120V (relative to neutral) line.

A double-pole breaker protects two hot 120V (relative to neutral) lines *on opposite legs*. So the two hot wires in a double-pole breaker (excluding a tandem double half-size breaker which is really two circuits in one on the *same* leg) are 240V from each other, each 120V to neutral.

There are a few different uses for a double-pole breaker:

- 240V hardwired appliance - e.g., water heater (typically 30A)
- 120V/240V circuit - e.g., clothes dryer (typically 30A, plug-in) or oven (typically 30A or 40A, hardwired)
- EV charging (could be any size, but typically 20A to 40A, plug-in or hardwired)
- 240V convenience receptacles. Arguably not so "convenient" since most people don't have appliances that need them. But some uses include welders, European appliances and computer servers.
- Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC)

The MWBC is the odd one. It is typically 15A or 20A and can connect to both ordinary 120V receptacles and to 240V receptacles. Most people don't have any 240V 15A or 20A receptacles, so the main use is to use one cable with 3 wires + ground (2 hots + neutral + ground) to connect to 2 120V circuits instead of two cables with 2 wires + ground (hot + neutral + ground). So that saves a bit on copper, and is particularly useful for kitchens or other areas with a large number of receptacles as you can have half on one 120V hot and half on the other 120V hot with a shared neutral.

MWBC is not as useful as it used to be due to AFCI and GFCI requirements, which complicate things a bit. But older houses often have MWBC predating those requirements, and if wired properly that's OK. (In my case, it turns out one of the old MWBCs was *not* wired properly with the old fuse box, but it is now on a double breaker like yours.)

Technically, an MWBC does not have to have a double-breaker. It just has to have a handle-tie. The difference is that with a double-breaker, if one hot overloads then both hots are turned off (common trip), while with a handle-tie there is no guarantee of common trip but if someone deliberately turns off the breaker then both hots are turned off (i.e., for maintenance purposes). Practically speaking, on most modern panels a double-breaker costs almost exactly what two single-breakers cost, so there is no point in using handle ties when you can just use a double breaker.

Comment: From some questions on here, the older MWBCs did not even need handle ties or be next to each other(just different phase).  Handle ties came after, guess because of all the shocks).